# mysql_query() returning false when searching database for a string of text

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP code executes the following query:

```
$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '%".$username."%'");
```

The query is being returned as false. I know this because $userid contains a boolean value after this query is executed.

I tried to perform the query in phpMyAdmin and noticed that the query only works if I encapsulate the string in quotations, but I don't think I can do this in the PHP code.

Is my syntax just wrong? Thanks for any help you can give...

UPDATE: When I echo $userid after this query is executed I get the following output:

```
Resource id #5Resource id #6
```

Which tells me that the query IS executing successfully, I am just not processing the results correctly.

Answer (score 4):

you need to use the `LIKE` operator:

```
$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%".$username."%'");
```

For completeness sake here is the link to the [Official Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

IF you want the exact match you should use the `=` operator then.

```
$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
```

Do you know if the value being passed in the `$username` variable is valid?

Comment: how do posts which lead to bad code get upvoted? (sadface)

Comment: I don't want to use the like operator because I want to make sure I have an exact match. I tried this anyway though just to see if it would work and I still get the same result...

Answer (score 2):

i think there is syntax error in query..

Try it i hope it will work for you..

```
$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username like '%".$username."%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching user names requires precision!! I believe that you do NOT want to use `LIKE`  operator with a wildcard.   This is because then you get "mae_potter" matching "annamae_potter'  since  `'anna_mae_potter' like '%mae_potter'` is true.

you want to use `=`:

```
$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
```

or `LIKE` without the wildcards:

```
$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username like '".$username."'");
```

Now you can be succinct with your match.

Comment: p.s. because you're using PHP i use double quotes and variables like this because double-quotes will still recognize variables in the statement

`$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");`

Comment: I agree, I do want to make sure that I have an exact match. But removing the % still gives me the same result...